# How do I use MacPorts (rsync) through a SOCKS5 proxy?

Tags: proxy, rsync, mac-osx, socks

MacPorts relies on rsync to do its job, and I rely on a SOCKS5 proxy to get full access to internet.  How do I make rsync run all its queries through my proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to just paste a url, but its [explained here](http://www.stokebloke.com/wordpress/2008/12/17/ssh-and-rsync-through-a-socks-proxy/). Essentially you install the connect utility, add something like this to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host stokebloke.com
    ProxyCommand connect -S user@socks-server:1080 %h %p
```

Then use:

```
rsync --progress -avrz -e ssh src_dir/ user@homebox.homelinux.net:~/dest_dir/
```

Comment: Yup, I've seen that one, but this would require that I add all hosts that rsync wants to use to .ssh/config.  Also, how do I instruct MacPorts to use custom rsync arguments?

Comment: You can set `rsync_server` and `rsync_options` in `/opt/local/etc/macports/macports.conf`. As an alternative method, use HTTP with the [daily tarball](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/PortTreeTarball) or the [Subversion repository](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/SyncingWithSVN).

Comment: I tried to add -e ssh to rsync_options, but it didn't help. Would I want to use something other that rsync.macports.org as rsync_server?   (I'll try the http/svn options, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to Sirex' answer, you can use [`nc(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) (netcat) to use the proxy.

Again, modify your [`~/.ssh/config`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) file:

```
Host server-prox
        Hostname www.server.com
        ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc -x localhost:8080 %h %p
```

then run

```
rsync -e ssh server-prox:path/to/files
```

and rsync (or rather ssh) will automatically use the proxy command.

This assumes there is a [SOCKS proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) running on `localhost` port 8080, which you can get with

```
ssh -D 8080 proxyserver.com
```

Personally I use

```
ssh -qfxND 8080 proxyserver.com
```

to set up a proxy tunnel, where `-qfxN` make the command run quietly in the background, see [`ssh(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh).

Comment: But what is the server? If that is "any server in general" than I would be required to add that for all the servers port wants to use to get data from. That's quite a lot, i.e., it's not a feasable solution.